# grep command to match only request url of access log

Tags: grep

I need to find all accessed URLs having keywords like config,tmp,backup or dump.

```
grep '/config/\|/tmp/\|/backup/\|/dump/' access.log
```

When I grep the access log I am getting unwanted logs like below

> 106.221.160.250 - - [11/Apr/2014:12:07:13 -0400] "GET url.com/perfect HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "file:///something/tmp/579928.html" "HTC_Smart_F3188 Mozilla/5.0 (like Gecko) Obigo/Q7" 0 20675

It's unwanted as `GET url.com/perfect HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "file:///something/tmp/579928.html` which doesn't contain the desired keyword.

How should I change my grep command?

Comment: Where should the keyword be? Is it supposed to be in the get request?

Comment: Better run like: `grep --color '..' access.log`

Comment: @stmfunk yes at get ....

Comment: @sat i prefer to get only relavant results.

Comment: @sat i am looking for solution, how to grep only the get part and not the referal part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

grep 'tmp\|config\|backup\|dump' accessl.log

Answer (score 0):

Your input data *does* contain one of the keywords you're looking for.  Note:

```
grep '/config/\|/tmp/\|/backup/\|/dump/' access.log
                ^^^^^
```

and:

```
"file:///something/tmp/579928.html"
                  ^^^^^
```

But someone could still put "/dump/" into their User Agent string if they wanted to mess with you.  If what you really want is to match the first part of the path of a GET, then you can look for exactly that, instead of matching keywords in the whole line.  For example:

```
egrep 'GET /(config|tmp|backup|dump)/' access.log
```

Much simpler to read, as well.  I used `egrep` so that we can use ERE instead of BRE, to avoid the ugly backslashes.  Note that this still could catch false positives if someone loaded their user agent with false data, so you could parse the log file more directly using awk to control field position:

```
awk '$6~/GET/ && $7 ~ /^\/(config|tmp|backup|dump)\//' access.log
```